# How to inject an NLog custom target with Autofac in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac, nlog

I've written a custom NLog target

```
[Target(TargetType)]
public class EmailTarget : TargetWithLayout
{
    public const string TargetType = "NVEmail";
    private const string DefaultLayout = "${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${message}${newline}${aspnet-request-querystring:QueryStringKeys=id}${newline}${exception:format=tostring}";

    public IEmailClient Client { get; set; }

    public string MailSubject { get; set; }
    public string Host { get; set; }

    public static void Register()
    {
        ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.Targets.RegisterDefinition(TargetType, typeof(EmailTarget));
    }

    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        Layout = DefaultLayout;
        var subject = GetMailSubject(logEvent);
        string message = this.Layout.Render(logEvent);

        SendMail(subject, message);
    }

    public void SendMail(string subject, string message)
    {
        Client.Host = Host;
        Client.SendEmail(subject, message);
    }

    public string GetMailSubject(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MailSubject))
        {
            return MailSubject;
        }
        if (logEvent?.Level != null)
        {
            return logEvent.Level.ToString();
        }
        return TargetType;                                                              
    }
}
```

And i'm trying to register it in an MVC project.
I'd like to inject the Client property using Autofac, but i can't seem to figure out how.

I figured out that I can just substitute the `ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance` method with:

```
private static object CreateInstance(Type itemType)
{
    if (_container.IsRegistered(itemType))
    {
        return _container.Resolve(itemType);
    }
    return Activator.CreateInstance(itemType);

}
```

But i get an error at runtime:

> Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Which is strange since there should be a default constructor in EMailTarget

Comment: I think you're registering to late. Do you have a stackstrace of the exception?

Comment: You could also use the internallogger, to log your custom code. E.g `InternalLogger.Trace("default activator")`, how to enable see https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging

Comment: is this the full code? as `EmailTarget ` has a default constructor?